# Error 'ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (54)' using pandas pd.to_numeric

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe:

```
                                          Financial KPI        Year                Value
0                                         Total Revenue         TTM             92478000
1                                         Total Revenue  12/31/2021             89113000
2                                         Total Revenue  12/31/2020             85528000
3                                         Total Revenue  12/31/2019             91244000
4                                         Total Revenue  12/31/2018             91247000
5   Net Income from Continuing & Discontinued Operation         TTM             27409000
6   Net Income from Continuing & Discontinued Operation  12/31/2021             31978000
7   Net Income from Continuing & Discontinued Operation  12/31/2020             17894000
8   Net Income from Continuing & Discontinued Operation  12/31/2019             27430000
9   Net Income from Continuing & Discontinued Operation  12/31/2018             28147000
10                                    Normalized Income         TTM             27409000
11                                    Normalized Income  12/31/2021             31978000
12                                    Normalized Income  12/31/2020             17894000
13                                    Normalized Income  12/31/2019             27430000
14                                    Normalized Income  12/31/2018             28147000
15                                            Basic EPS         TTM                     
16                                            Basic EPS  12/31/2021                 3.60
17                                            Basic EPS  12/31/2020                 1.88
18                                            Basic EPS  12/31/2019                 2.77
19                                            Basic EPS  12/31/2018                 2.64
20                                    Net_Profit_Margin         TTM   0.2963840048443954
21                                    Net_Profit_Margin  12/31/2021  0.35884775509746053
22                                    Net_Profit_Margin  12/31/2020  0.20921803386025628
23                                    Net_Profit_Margin  12/31/2019   0.3006225066853711
24                                    Net_Profit_Margin  12/31/2018  0.30847041546571397
25                                    Price To Earnings         TTM                9.125
26                                         Total Assets         TTM                     
27                                         Total Assets  12/31/2021           3169495000
28                                         Total Assets  12/31/2020           2819627000
29                                         Total Assets  12/31/2019           2434079000
30                                         Total Assets  12/31/2018           2354507000
31              Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest         TTM                     
32              Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest  12/31/2021           2899429000
33              Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest  12/31/2020           2546703000
34              Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest  12/31/2019           2169269000
35              Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest  12/31/2018           2089182000
36                 Total Equity Gross Minority Interest         TTM                     
37                 Total Equity Gross Minority Interest  12/31/2021            270066000
38                 Total Equity Gross Minority Interest  12/31/2020            272924000
39                 Total Equity Gross Minority Interest  12/31/2019            264810000
40                 Total Equity Gross Minority Interest  12/31/2018            265325000
41                                           Total Debt         TTM                     
42                                           Total Debt  12/31/2021            303870000
43                                           Total Debt  12/31/2020            282255000
44                                           Total Debt  12/31/2019            265060000
45                                           Total Debt  12/31/2018            249529000
46                   Current_Ratio (assets/liabilities)  12/31/2021    1.093144546736616
47                   Current_Ratio (assets/liabilities)  12/31/2020   1.1071675809860828
48                   Current_Ratio (assets/liabilities)  12/31/2019   1.1220733804797838
49                   Current_Ratio (assets/liabilities)  12/31/2018    1.126999466776949
50                                 Debt_to_Assets_Ratio  12/31/2021  0.09587331735812803
51                                 Debt_to_Assets_Ratio  12/31/2020  0.10010366619414554
52                                 Debt_to_Assets_Ratio  12/31/2019  0.10889539739671555
53                                 Debt_to_Assets_Ratio  12/31/2018  0.10597929842637971
```

I'm trying to convert the values of column 'Value' from string to the float type with the following line:

```
df_global['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(['Value'], errors='coerce')
```

However, with this line, I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (54)
```

Not sure why this is happening. To my understanding the to_numeric function should just convert all the values of that column to float. The index, without the column headers, go from 0 to 53 so why is it complaining? How can I prevent this.
Any help?

Comment: `df_global['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df_global['Value'], errors='coerce')`